# Why does calling IEnumerable<string>.Count() create an additional assembly dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Assume this chain of dll references

```
Tests.dll >> Automation.dll >> White.Core.dll
```

with the following line of code in Tests.dll,  where everything builds

```
result.MissingPaths
```

Now when I change this to

```
result.MissingPaths.Count()
```

I get the following build error for Tests.dll "White.UIItem is not defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to White.Core.dll." And I don't want to do that because it breaks my layering.

Here is the type definition for result, which is in Automation.dll

```
public class HasResult
        {
            public HasResult(IEnumerable<string> missingPaths )
            {   MissingPaths = missingPaths;           }

            public IEnumerable<string> MissingPaths { get; set; }

            public bool AllExist
            {
                get { return !MissingPaths.Any(); }
            }
        }
```

Down the call chain the input param to this ctor is created via (The TreeNode class is in White.Core.dll)

```
assetPaths.Where(assetPath => !FindTreeNodeUsingCache(treeHandle, assetPath));
```

Why does this dependency leak when calling Count() on IEnumerable ? I then suspected that lazy evaluation was causing this (for some reason) - so I slotted in an ToArray() in the above line but didn't work.

**Update 2011 01 07:** Curiouser and Curiouser!
it won't build until I add a White.Core reference. So I add a reference and build it (in order to find the elusive dependency source). Open it up in Reflector and the only references listed are Automation, mscorlib, System.core and NUnit. So the compiler threw away the White reference as it was not needed. ILDASM also confirms that there is no White AssemblyRef entry.

Any ideas on how to get to the bottom of this thing (primarily for 'now I wanna know why' reasons)? What are the chances that this is an VS2010/MSBuild bug?

**Update 2011 01 07 #2**
As per Shimmy's suggestion, tried calling the method explcitly as an extension method

```
Enumerable.Count(result.MissingPaths)
```

and it stops cribbing (not sure why).
However I moved some code around after that and now I'm getting the same issue at a different location using IEnumerable - this time reading and filtering lines out of a file on disk (totally unrelated to White). Seems like it's a 'symptom-fix'.
`var lines = File.ReadLines(aFilePath).ToArray();`
once again, if I remove the ToArray() it compiles again - it seems that any method that causes the enumerable to be evaluated (ToArray, Count, ToList, etc.) causes this. Let me try and get a working tiny-app to demo this issue...

**Update 2011 01 07 #3**
Phew! More information.. It turns out the problem is just in one source file - this file is LINQ-phobic. Any call to an Enumerable extension method has to be explicitly called out.
The refactorings that I did caused a new method to be moved into this source file, which had some LINQ :) Still no clue as to why this class dislikes LINQ.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using G.S.OurAutomation.Constants;
using G.S.OurAutomation.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace G.S.AcceptanceTests
{
    public abstract class ConfigureThingBase : OurTestFixture
    {
      ....
        private static IEnumerable<string> GetExpectedThingsFor(string param)
        {
                // even this won't compile - although it compiles fine in an adjoining source file in the same assembly
                //IEnumerable<string> s = new string[0];
                //Console.WriteLine(s.Count()); 



                // this is the line that is now causing a build failure   
            //  var expectedInfo = File.ReadLines(someCsvFilePath))
//                  .Where(line => !line.StartsWith("REM", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
//                  .Select(line => line.Replace("%PLACEHOLDER%", param))
//                  .ToArray();

                // Unrolling the LINQ above removes the build error

            var expectedInfo =
                Enumerable.ToArray(
                    Enumerable.Select(
                        Enumerable.Where(
                            File.ReadLines(someCsvFilePath)),
                            line => !line.StartsWith("REM", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
                        line => line.Replace("%PLACEHOLDER%", param)));
```

**Update 2011 01 11 #4**
Narrowed it down to what seems the perp but no motive :)
Resumed the quest post the weekend.. and using the evergreen process of elimination, was able to zone in on the offending bit.
The problem is the following using directive in the source file in Tests.dll

```
using G.S.OurAutomation.Framework;
```

Next I went after the most probable suspect within this namespace and I had WhiteExtensions under the spotlight.

```
namespace G.S.OurAutomation.Framework
{
   public static class WhiteExtensions
   {
        public static T PollAndGet<T>(this Window parentWindow, string automationId) where T : UIItem ...
        public static Window WaitForWindowWithTitle(this Application application, string windowTitle) ...
        public static bool HasTreeNode(this Tree treeHandle, string assetPath) ...
        public static HasTreeNodesResult HasTreeNodes(this Tree treeHandle, IEnumerable<string> assetPaths)...
   }
}
```

This led to 3 fixes, both of which work.

1. Turn the extension methods into normal static methods.
2. Move this class into a subnamespace `G.S.OurAutomation.Framework.White`
3. Make this an internal class (as it is meant for internal consumption.. once again the guideline of choosing the most restrictive access modifier bites me.)

Although my specific instance is fixed, can this update help someone explain the reason for this ? If not shimmy gets the tick :) for pointing towards the right direction.

Comment: could you provide more code? And perhaps rename the DLLs to something more meaningful? Perhaps W.Type is not referenced where an extension method is declared?

Comment: Try adding W.dll as reference to the T project.

Comment: @James - Named the assemblies :) What the code is doing (in short) is : Check if certain nodes exist in a Tree shown on the GUI ? result is a type that wraps a boolean success value + a list of missing nodes if any. So Tests.dll uses Automation.dll - Driver.HasNodes() to do its thing, however the impl. detail that Automation.dll uses White to get the job done shouldn't creep out of the Automation layer. The code involves returning an IEnumerable<string> (full paths Root\parent\child) from the inner layer to the client for error reporting.

Comment: This is going to seem completely odd, but try commenting out the `AllExist` get code and replacing it with something generic (`return true;` or `return false;`) I just want to see if getting rid of the LINQ (extension method) from there might help (It probably won't, but I have no idea what is going on here)

Comment: Also perhaps triple check you are using the same version of the .net framework and linq dlls everywhere, and have `using System.Linq;` in every file that needs it (You probs already do, but I really want to know what's going on as well)

Comment: @James - n-checked. Attached the header of that file in case I've been looking at this for too long. See update #3.

Comment: Does this happen for IEnumerables of anything other than string?

Comment: If it's just that file... Move everything out of it :P Although it may be one of your using statements that conflict with something or... ???

Comment: @Allon - IEnumerables of anything. It's unable to resolve any of the extension methods in Enumerable. @James - yeah that's one thing I didn't try - the switcheroo:)

Comment: @James - the ruse didn't trick the compiler :) However got some further insight - see last update in chain above.

Answer (score 4):

Try to call `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(result.MissingPaths)` (with or without the full namespace reference).

[`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535181.aspx) is an extension method, you can call it explicitly.

**Update after Gishu's Update#2:**

The reason for all is the same, the functions `ToArray`, `Count`, `ToList` etc. are all extension methods declared in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

BTW, **important**: did you double check that the namespace System.Linq is imported (`using System.Linq`) to your file? that might even solve all your problems.

Comment: This worked but I don't know why! I got too happy about it. Couple of refactorings later.. I get this same error in a different place where I am using IEnumerable<string> again - this time to read lines from a file and filter some unwanted lines. Any particular reason you suggested this...

Comment: Because IEnumerable<T> does not contain the Count function--something in the System.Linq namespace does (this is called an extension method). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @shimmy - Yeah I knew that they were extension methods; what I meant was I still can't see the difference between calling `collection.Select(..` and `Enumerable.Select(collection,..` unless collection has an instance method Select which would override the extension method. Any other reason why this resolution should fail ?

Comment: Is the `System.Linq` namespace imported to your current file?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler presumably needed to see White.Core.dll to figure out if there was a Count() method defined on your class.  Since there wasn't it used the IEnumerable<> extension method's Count and thus didn't need White.Core.dll after all, but it couldn't know that without examining it.

But I can't explain how that could be the case for `IEnumerable<string>` unless the compiler is checking that you aren't using covariance??

Comment: "...Count() method defined on your class" which class did you mean ? HasResult ?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
public HasResult(IEnumerable<string> missingPaths )
{   MissingPaths = missingPaths;           }
```

to

```
public HasResult(IEnumerable<string> missingPaths )
{   MissingPaths = missingPaths.ToArray();           }
```

Should eliminate lazy loading scenarios in all cases where result is used.

Comment: tried this - didn't work as mentioned towards the end of my post

Comment: @Gishu, was suggested just in case, you have missed a place where result is getting constructed. Yet another possibility is MissingPaths setter used in A.dll elsewhere - can you make it private? Also, what is the type from W for which complier is cribbing?

Comment: Its asking for a UIItem type defined in White.dll - however I've kept Tests.dll White free all this time. (Did a find-replace too to doublecheck). Also tried forcing evaluation at diff places up the call stack but doesn't work.

Comment: @Gishu, explaination by Hightechrider (and solution by Shimmy) does make sense - only thing that baffles me is what's the relationship between `IEnumerable<string>` and `UIItem` that compiler is trying to investigate!